# What its wrong in this code on Opencart 3.0.3.3

Tags: opencart, opencart-3, opencart-module

Whats its wrong in this code?

```
// Begin LJK - option display names
if (strlen(trim($option['display'])) != 0){
$option['name'] = $option['display'];
}
// End LJK - option display names
```

I have This Error on cart! But module works fine

Notice: Undefined index: display in /home/opencart/public_html/storage/modification/catalog/controller/checkout/cart.php on line 101

Answer (score 0):

you should check if this display key exist in this array or not ( $option['display'] ) before use trim and strlen methods
so you should change your code to be like this :-

```
if ( !empty($option['display']) && strlen(trim($option['display'] ) ) != 0 ) {
$option['name'] = $option['display'];
}
```